# Action Button works differently if added to the DataView

Tags: xpages, dataview, view-scope

I have a button that calls a Dialog that has a combo box bound to a sessionScope variable. The combo box contains a list of form names that I use to then call an XPage to create a new document. The first value in the forms list is "" so the user needs to select a value. I have a button with the onClick event of:

```
var c = getComponent("CreateDocDialog");
sessionScope.put("ssSelectedForm","")
c.show();
```

I have the button and dialog on a customControl with a repeatControl and when the button to open the dialog is clicked the ssSelectedForm is null and the current value of the combo is blank, which is exactly what I want it to be. However, if I add the same button and dialog to a customControl with a dataView control the dialog displays but ssSelectedForm is not null so the combo box displays the last value of ssSelected. I have placed the button outside the dataView, in several of the facets on the dataview, but all with the same results.

Very confusing.

Comment: I would use a viewScope variable instead of sessionScope for a combobox.  Its a simple change, try that and see if you get better results.

Answer (score 0):

Bill,

I am going to answer the same as my comment since I am pretty confident about what I said.

Go ahead and change the scope from sessionScope to viewScope.   I had a similar issue once, and I 'fixed' it by clearing out the sessionScope variable after I used it.  This worked, but I realized that it was not necessary, and that by changing to viewScope the lifecycle will be shorter and there was no need to clear out the value when I was done with it.

I don't know why this fails when added to the data view, but if this fixes it that would be all that matters.

Comment: I believe this really needs to be a session scope variable because using this sessionScope variable I call a different XPage and use the variable in a dynamicContent control to display a specific panel. At this point I believe I'm in a new view. When I started developing this process I started using a viewScope but it lost focus. Now this was several months ago so I could be wrong, great memory just not very long. I guess what I could do is bind it to a view scope then in my action button on the dialog copy the viewScope to the sessionScope.

Comment: Yes, you didn't say how the combobox was bound in your question, but I would always bind it to viewScope, and as you say then assign that to a sessionScope variable.  That should fix this issue without causing unintended consequences.

Comment: Steve - bound the combo to a viewScope called vsNewForm, then on the way out sessionScope.put("ssSelectedForm",viewScope.get("vsNewForm") and it works in the dataView custom control now as well as in the cc with the repeatControl. What I don't understand is why? I hate doing something like this with out a why other than BECAUSE! :-) as Alice says curiouser and curiouser. By definition a sessionScope variable is available at any point within the current login -- Sooo ?????

Comment: I am glad it fixed your issue, without actually looking over your shoulder I don't think I can speculate why, but I totally understand your frustration.

Comment: I have found that in general the best binding for comboboxes is viewScope, and to use sessionScope to carry things between pages, like you did it.  If (and only if) my answer helped you with your specific problem, I would appreciate you accepting the answer.   I would imagine that if given all the code a reason could be figured out, but I would venture to guess that the most important thing was to get around the problem at hand.  (And if you are like me, onto the next problem :)